# Link between block and category

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, widget, luma-theme

I have tried to figure out from the Luma how the widgets are tied to categories.

Could you let me know where I can find the "link" between the block and category. The Add CMS Block in category doesn't have this default block...

**How the e.g. sale-block is defined into Sale category?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Magento Admin -> Content -> Widgets`.

Here you'll find "**Sale Category content**". Click on it to open that widget.

In ***Storefront Properties*** tab -> ***Layout Updates*** you can define:

- Container (position where block will be placed)
- Category (where block will be applied).

In ***Widget Options*** tab you just have to select CMS block which will be displayed (it's Sale Block in this example).